# How to populate a file with default value if we know the position where the column need to be placed in a file?

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I'm having a file containing data:

```
Emp_Id|Name|Age
100156|Sam|23
1508|Amy|26
1234|Annie|30
```

So I have two columns which I need to add:
`Dep_Id` having datatype number (at 2nd position in exis. File)

`Department` having datatype varchar (at 5th position in exis. File)

Now if I know the position where I need to add the columns how to prepare the code in unix for populating the new columns with default values (like if it's varchar give `default` and if it's number give `0`) in the existing file containing data.

Output i want like this:

```
Emp_Id|Dep_Id|Name|Age|Department
100156|0|Sam|23|default
1508|0|Amy|26|default
1234|0|Annie|30|default
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Awk:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR == 1 { print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS "Department" } NR > 1 { print $1 FS "0" FS $2 FS $3 FS "default" }' file.txt
```

This results in your expected output:

```
Emp_Id|Dep_Id|Name|Age|Department
100156|0|Sam|23|default
1508|0|Amy|26|default
1234|0|Annie|30|default
```

Explanation:

- `-F'|'` tells `awk` to use `|` as the field separator. This allows you to refer to e.g. the first field as `$1`.
- `NR` refers to the row number. For the first row (`NR == 1`) we want to print the 1st column, then a field separator (`FS` which we set to `|`), the 2nd col, etc.
- For rows greater than 1 we print, similarly to the first row, the data.

Comment: I want a generic code suppose for 100columns i can't go with this approach

Comment: Then clarify this in your question. Do you have hundreds of columns and a fixed number of columns to insert? Or vice versa?

Comment: Hundreds of columns i have in my file

Comment: And the position to insert the new columns is always the same?

Comment: No positions will also change.